# ASP MVC 5 - Why does slash "/" in img tag triggers new requests

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Recently I noticed that my application was generating many more requests that I expected. Debugging revealed that in some cases 1 page visit generates 2-5 separate requests (both Owin and Ninject dependencies are re-initialized).

After a while I found out that these additional requests are created in my razor views when generating an image tag like:

```
<img src="/" alt="">
```

This line causes no problems (even if the image does not exist):

```
<img src="/a.jpg" alt="">
```

Of course I don't want to generate invalid images and I fixed that part, but I'm still wondering what is behind this.

What is the purpose of this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the src of the image tag to "/" will actually cause the browser to load the entire website again from the root until it realizes that the request is a HTML document not an image. Because it is loading it from the root it is considered a new request therefore OWIN and Ninject reinitialize everything as they are per request not per application lifetime.

The image tag in the browser does not have the ability to detect what the URL you put in the src is until it downloads it that is why it has to download the entire page when you set the src to "/" i.e. the root of the website.